# Multidimensional Array keeps repeating

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I'm brand new to java, and I'm unfortunately struggling with it.  I can't seem to get the array to stop repeating itself for every iteration.  I'm also having problems with lines combining in the output.  I've tried to use scanner, but I can't seem to get that to work either.

This is what I've tried:

```
`// Online Java Compiler
```

// Use this editor to write, compile and run your Java code online

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ArrayStudies {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //* Define and initialize the ID Array *//
    int[] id = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    //* Define the UserID Array *//
    String[] userid = new String[10];
    //* Initialize the Names Array *//
    userid[0] = "Admin";
    userid[1] = "Vale.Vicky";
    userid[2] = "Lane.Lois";
    userid[3] = "Kent.Clark";
    userid[4] = "Wayne.Bruce";
    userid[5] = "Parker.Peter";
    userid[6] = "Rogers.Steve";
    userid[7] = "Luther.Lex";
    userid[8] = "Osborn.Harry";
    userid[9] = "Prince.Diana";
    //* Define the Password Array *//
    String[] password = new String[10];
    //* Initialize the Password Array *//
    password[0] = "Password1";
    password[1] = "ZZZZZZZ";
    password[2] = "VVVVVV";
    password[3] = "AAAAAA";
    password[4] = "FFFFFFFF";
    password[5] = "RRRRRRR";
    password[6] = "QQQQQQ";
    password[7] = "GGGGGG";
    password[8] = "YYYYYY";
    password[9] = "LLLLLLL";

    //*Use data to Create Multidemensional Array*//
    for (int l = 0; l < id.length; l++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < userid.length; i++)
        System.out.println("ID: " + id[i] + " " + "UserID: " + userid[i] + " " + "Password:" + " " + password[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you decide to use nested for loops? I'd suggest remove the outer one (`for (int l` etc).

Comment: Your arrays have 1 dimension, so no need for nested loops.

Comment: I'm trying to get them to output in a table.  ID: 1 UserID: Admin Password: Password1

Comment: I know, it's because I'm trying to make it work.

Comment: I've tried to use the variable in the for loops, but every time I tried to do it, it generated errors.

Comment: It still repeats everything ten times.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.online-java.com/GBLifCIPhE) what you mean by output in a tabular form?

Comment: Your code doesn't show any multi-dimensional arrays. Code using multidimensional arrays should look something like this: `Foo [][] foo2D;`  `Foo [][][] foo 3D;`  `Foo [][][][] foo4D;` ...  What you are doing is using parallel arrays. In your case, you have 3 single dimension arrays.  Programmers using Object-Oriented languages tend to not like parallel arrays.

Comment: Off-topic:  An advantage of using a class is that values related to one entity can be glued into a single Object. You can avoid parallel arrays by creating a class:  `class Person { int id; String name; String password;  Person (int id, String name, String pass) { this.id = id; this.name = name; this.password = pass; } // getters & setters, if any ... }`. That way, you can have one array:  `Person [] = { new Person (0, "Admin","Password1"), new Person (1, "Vale.Vicky", "ZZZZZZZ"), ... }`

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Java records make it even simpler `record Person(int id, String name, String pass) { }` and you're done.

Comment: Hi everyone, first: thank you for this information.  It really is appreciated as I was at my wits end. The problem is that I have to use arrays.  It's part of an assignment.  I thought nested would be the way to go.  When I tried to use the multidimensional arrays Foo [] [] []. I kept getting string cannot be converted to INT issues.  Also, sorry about the hidden picture.  This is my first time trying to post here and I'm not the best at getting it organized in the post.

Comment: Well, a 3D array seems inappropriate. You could use a 2D array, where column 0 is ID, column 1 is name, and column 2 is password. But, all 3 columns would be `String`. Example:  `String [][] person = {{"0","Admin","Password"},{"1","Vale.Vicky","ZZZZZZZ"},{"2","Lane.Lois", "VVVVVV"}, ...`  (I like having 1D array of `Person` class or record better.)

Answer (score 0):

Use one *for-loop*.

```java
//*Use data to Create Multidemensional Array*//
String[][] strings = new String[10][2];
for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    strings[index][0] = userid[index];
    strings[index][1] = password[index];
}
```

Output

```
strings[0] = [Admin, Password1]
strings[1] = [Vale.Vicky, ZZZZZZZ]
strings[2] = [Lane.Lois, VVVVVV]
strings[3] = [Kent.Clark, AAAAAA]
strings[4] = [Wayne.Bruce, FFFFFFFF]
strings[5] = [Parker.Peter, RRRRRRR]
strings[6] = [Rogers.Steve, QQQQQQ]
strings[7] = [Luther.Lex, GGGGGG]
strings[8] = [Osborn.Harry, YYYYYY]
strings[9] = [Prince.Diana, LLLLLLL]
```